# (Lua) Importing/requiring math modules doesn't work

Tags: math, lua

I have some code here:

```
require "math"

local dozenDonuts
local oneDonut
local function roundToFirstDecimal(t)
    return math.round(t*10)*0.1
end
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

```
lua: f:\my codes\donut.lua:6: attempt to call field 'round' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    f:\my codes\donut.lua:6: in function 'roundToFirstDecimal'
    f:\my codes\donut.lua:17: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Is `round` *not* an attribute of math? How can I round to the first decimal?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313171/lua-rounding-numbers-and-then-truncate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.round` is not part of the standard Lua math library. But it is simple to write:

```
function math.round(x)
    return math.floor(x+0.5)
end
```