# Math.round(number, 10) in lua

Tags: lua, math.round

I would like to round a number according to the following pattern

e.g 1246 to 1250
e.g 1234 to 1230

As far as I know in java there is math.round(1245,10) to do that. How can I do that in lua?

I tried it with math.floor an ceil.

Comment: 1246 -> 124.6 -> 125 -> 1250

Answer (score 3):

Transform your value to match your scale (e.g., divide by 10), [round it (floor + 0.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313171/lua-rounding-numbers-and-then-truncate), transform back.

```lua
function round(value, scale)
    return math.floor(value / scale + 0.5) * scale
end
```